# How to pass a data one Component to Another Components After Form Submit

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In this code, I want to get my user email in Login Component after submitting the Registration Component.

> Component: Registration

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Button, Container, Form,Row,Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { useNavigate,Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const Register = () => {
  const [data,setData] = useState({
    'first_name': 'dfdf',
    'last_name': '',
    'email': 'maruf@mail.com',
    'password': '',
    'password_confirm': ''
  })
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setData({
      ...data,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    navigate('/login',{replace:true,state:{email:data.email}});
  }
  return <>
  <Container fluid={'md'}>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={6}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicFirstName">
          <Form.Label column >First Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='first_name' value={data.first_name} onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicLastName">
          <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='last_name' value={data.last_name} onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='email' value={data.email} onChange={handleInputChange} type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='password' value={data.password} onChange={handleInputChange} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword_Confirm">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name='password_confirm' value={data.password_confirm} onChange={handleInputChange} type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type='submit' onSubmit={handleSubmit} >Register</Button>
      </Form>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
  </>;
};
export default Register;
```

here I want to send the user email address after done the registration then send the data into the Login Components.

> Component: Login

```
 React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Container, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Login = () => {
  const [data,setData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const uselocation = useLocation();
  if (uselocation.state) {
    if (uselocation.state.email) {
      setData({
        ...data,
        email: uselocation.state.email,
      });
    }
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <>
     <Container fluid={'md'}>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={6}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted">
            We'll never share your email with anyone else.
          </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
          <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
      </Col>
      </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

after a navigate to login Component I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of
> renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap setData from Login component with useEffect and add location as a dependency.